# Responsive image, fixed ratio. Can't get code working

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

sorry I have been trying numerous tutorials on the net to try and make this image responsive/scaling with a fixed aspect ratio, but nothing is working.

It's a 900x400px image and I simply want to keep it all visible on smaller screens etc.

Here's the codepen [link](http://codepen.io/Creationsphere/pen/gvzmH)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="aboutsec1">
<div class="parallaxbg">
<div class="parallaxcontainer">
<div class="parallaxcontent">
<h1>header</h1>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<section id="aboutsec2">
<div class="parallaxbg"></div>
<div class="parallaxbg2"></div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Basic Parallax Background */
.parallaxbg {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

/* Basic Parallax Container */
.parallaxcontainer {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

/* Basic Parallax Content */
.parallaxcontent {
    max-width: 450px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

#aboutsec1{
    height: 100%;
}

/* About Page Section 1 */
#aboutsec1 .parallaxbg {
    background: none;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: center;
}

/* About Page Section 2 */
#aboutsec2 {
}

#aboutsec2 .parallaxbg2 {
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url('http://s16.postimg.org/k5xrwvp7p/900x400.png');
    z-index: 1;
    background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 44.444444444444%; /* 400px/900px */
}
```

Comment: Hi ! I've tried your codepen on my phone and background image seems responsive. Coukd you bring more details on what you aim to achieve please ?

Comment: Are you sure? Theres a black section with a background image which says 900x400 and has white corners. I want to display the whole image in the black section. This doesn't currently work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, I figured it out myself eventually. Here's the code for a fixed aspect ratio responsive background image if anyone else needs it...

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
    <div class="responsiveimage"></div>
</div>

.imagecontainer {
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 900px; \* For a 900px wide image *\
}

.responsiveimage {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding-bottom: 44.444444444444%; /* 400px/900px x 100 (for a 900x400 image) */
}
```

Set padding bottom to be the correct ratio using the sum, which means the image will always keep the same aspect ratio.